# How to run .sh file containing SQL commands in Windows command line when psql command not found?

Tags: bash, powershell, command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux, psql

Thank you beforehand. So, what I'm trying to do is run a bash script in Windows using Powershell; I needed to use psql command so I already searched around and added the corresponding Environment variables, activated Windows Subsystem for Linux, downloaded Ubuntu in Windows.

In short before having done all that, I ran "psql" on Powershell and command was not found, but then after setup when I asked for version for example (psql --version), command "psql" was recognized. I thought that would be it and I could happily run my .sh file but when I tried to run it the "psql command not found" came back a bit different, therefore I'm not sure what to do next.

To give some more context, my .sh file contains some lines in the form:

```
psql some_setup do_something.sql
```

I run the command like this, and the message comes up:
[image]

Weird thing for me is that if I ask for the version, psql is recognized:
[image]

Comment: Looks like `psql` isn't in path in Bash.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You mean I should add that psql path but to the script itself?

Comment: It's probably enough to change `psql` to `psql.exe` in your `.sh` file - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64757302/45375).

Comment: Related to to the comment from @mklement0 - [WSL - How to fallback to exe when linux binary is not available in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63800125/wsl-how-to-fallback-to-exe-when-linux-binary-is-not-available-in-bash)